# allowing single touch to a view

Tags: iphone

hi
i have five buttons in a view and i am able to tap all five buttons at a time ..
in that one is for increment and the another one is for decrement if two buttons are tapped at an time the application hangs... and some times it crashes .....

can any one please help how to make the make the screen to allow on tap at once .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like that once user touch the button. dosable userinteraction of user upto your action over. and that enable it. thats it.

example:

```
button.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```